# How to make sure hashtag attach the ajax updated content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I had created a pagination with ajax. When user click the page number, it called the ajax function. I want to remember the previous ajax html data when user hit the back button. Therefore, I am trying to add the hash to each page. eg. when user click page 3, url is www.site.com/#3, page 4, is www.site.com/#4. It works OK so far. However, when I click the back button, it always load the second last page no matter the hash is 3 or 4. So, how can I make sure each hash attach to the ajax's update content? if the url is www.site.com/#4, it will always load the page 4 content. Appreicate.

```js
$('#pagination a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $this = $(this).attr('href');//href is the page number
  var data = {
    action: 'post_pagination_ajax',
    post_num : $this,
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: ajax_front_gallery.ajaxurl,
    type:'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
      $('.post-content').html(data);
    }
  });

  window.location.hash = $this;
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a click event, however when you hit back button there is no any click event, browser just loads previous page from history. So what you have to do is to make also a `load` event. Final result will look something like this:

```
function loadContent ( url,data ) {

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type:'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            $('.post-content').html(data);
        }
    });

}

$('#pagination a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var hash = $(this).attr('href');

    var data = {
        action: 'post_pagination_ajax',
        post_num : $(this).attr('href')
    };

    loadContent( ajax_front_gallery.ajaxurl,data );

    window.location.hash = hash;

    return false;
});

$( window ).load(function() {

    var data = {
        action: 'post_pagination_ajax',
        post_num : window.location.hash
    };

    loadContent( ajax_front_gallery.ajaxurl,data );

});
```

**Edit:**

Even though this solves your problem i would recommend doing it other way. Since you change hash and want to load content based on hash. There is a `hashchange` event for that. So you could do:

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){

    var data = {
        action: 'post_pagination_ajax',
        post_num : location.hash
    };

    loadContent( ajax_front_gallery.ajaxurl,data );

});

//Trigger hash-change if page laoded with existing hash
$(window).hashchange();
```

And you won't need any click event on `a` preventing the default behaviour, because default behaviour of changing hash in url is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it doesn't change everything if the url hash had changed. If there's any way I can cathe the page?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't change **everything**. Page is cached by default, you can cache server requests

Comment: The haschange() works, but problem is that, ajax will run twice if I go to the the page from my front page.

Comment: I was thinking in what way I can transfer the hash number to a php script instead of window.location.hash

Answer (score 0):

So I am not really sure if there is a standard how browser handle the url fragment (hash). The problem is that setting the hash is originally used for saying the browser where to scroll (with anchors etc.: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp). So when you set the hash most browser will put a new state in the history but will not use the current state of the DOM but use the old one before the hash was set.

But I can say, when ever I implement asynchrone paging with Javascript I do it similiar like you do, but I check the hash on the page load and load the specific page, so you always have the result you want.

I think this is the way the Google search works and it was the source of my idea.